# CamlQuery - How to use Where clause in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm very new to CamlQuery and need a bit of help getting this to work.

I installed a tool called CamlDesigner to help me generate the XML needed to filter a collection in Sharepoint, but the XML query that CamlDesigner constructs does not work in my C# codebehind. I have an ID field that I am trying to filter by and I simply want to retrieve an item from Sharepoint where ID = 1 (or 2 or 3 or whatever).

Here is the Caml query generated by the designer:

```
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ID' />
         <Value Type='Counter'>1</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
```

Here is my C# code where I am attempting to incorporate this Caml query. The C# works, **but it is returning every item from "My SP Coll" as opposed to only returning the item where ID equals 1**.

```
// Sharepoint web service to retrieve categories items there
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://myweb.dev.com/SP");
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My SP Coll");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value type='Counter'>" + ID.ToString() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(collListItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem in collListItem) {
     string ID = oListItem["ID"].ToString();
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The query needs to be wrapped in a `<View>...</View>` element, in addition to the `<Query>` element.
2. As per the generated query, the field name is `ID` not `Id`.

On a side note, make sure you're disposing of the client context.

And of course, to get an item by ID you can bypass this entire process and just use

```
var item = list.GetItemById(ID);
```

Comment: Wrapping it with View tags was one of the first things I tried. Sadly, it still returns every item in the collection. Also, I fixed the "Id". That was also due to some testing that I'd simply forgotten to change back to "ID". Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jagd I can't see any other mistakes, but you could just go easy on yourself and use `GetItemById` instead of all of this.

Comment: I'm just going to use GetItemById(). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewXml` property just points to a view within a list and doesn't appear to handle filtering.

If you were to set up an already-filtered view and point the `ViewXml` to that, then you would still grab all items in the view, but since the view itself is filtered, your result set would match it.